# How does alignment work with pointers to zero-sized arrays?

Tags: c, gcc, struct, sizeof

I was investigating some code I saw that deals with 0-size arrays.  Specifically, they are used in the case of dynamically allocated size of a struct such as in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

Specifically, this is the code in Callgrind:

```
struct _EventGroup {
    int size;
    const char* name[0];
};
```

I was playing around with this, using gcc 4.1.2 on a 64-bit Red Hat, and noticed that the **sizeof** function returns a size of **8 bytes** for the entire *struct _EventGroup* when the *name* field is a pointer.  Now if I change it to:

```
struct _EventGroup {
    int size;
    const char name[0];
};
```

I get **4 bytes** because gcc identifies the 0-size array as taking up no space, and the int as taking up 4 bytes.  That makes sense.  If I then change it to:

```
struct _EventGroup {
    int size;
    const char* name;
};
```

sizeof returns **16 bytes** because the char* takes up 8 bytes in a 64 bit system, and the int has to get padded to 8 bytes.  This makes sense.  Now, if I do one last change:

```
struct _EventGroup {
    const char* name[0];
};
```

I get **0 bytes** because gcc is detecting my zero-size array.  What I want clarified is what's happening in the first case I presented.  How much space is gcc allocating for a pointer to a zero size array and why?  I'm asking because this code seems designed to be efficient with memory allocation, however it would make sense that gcc either gives the pointer a size of 0 bytes if it detects it points to essentially nothing, or 8 bytes if it is being treated as a normal pointer.  Alignment would dictate that I get either 4 bytes or 16 bytes with my original struct.  Why am I getting 8 bytes?

Comment: Zero-sized arrays are a GCC extension, not part of C. Bear in mind that you're not supposed to use structs like this for anything but dynamically allocated memory, so "0 bytes" makes sense if you think of it as "0 bytes for the preamble before the actual array".

Comment: this line: const char* name[0]; is defining an array of char* entries, of which there are 0/none.

Comment: I get those parts, but my question is specifically pertaining to the alignment being enforced in gcc.  When I declare char* name[0] with the int, it's apparently padded from 0 bytes up to 4 bytes.  In the case where it's just char name[0], it's padded from 0 bytes to 0 bytes (not padded at all).  Why is the case with the pointer treated differently? I would assume if it was being treated like a pointer it would be 8 bytes.

Comment: If you take out the `0` then this Q and A apply to Standard C (this technique is called *flexible array member*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gcc is adding the right amount of padding such that if you actually allocate extra space for the array, the pointer `&(eventGroup->name)` will be properly aligned.

It seems you're on a platform that has 4-byte ints and 8-byte pointers, so this means you have:

```
bytes 0-3   -- the int
bytes 4-7   -- padding
bytes 8-15  -- where the first (char *) would be stored, 8-byte aligned
```

Since it's actually an array of zero size, you don't actually have that first `char *`, but you *do* have the padding. Hence, the struct has size 8.

In your second example, there is no alignment requirement for a one-byte char, so you have:

```
bytes 0-3   -- the int
byte  4     -- where the first (char) would be stored, "1-byte aligned"
```

Again, no actual `char` in the struct, so it has size 4.